# Is it possible to still play 'The Matrix Online'?

Tags: the-matrix-online

I bought the game a day too late, when I took it home it gave me troubles, I was younger and didn't fully know about installing PC games etc. and eventually after a few weeks discovered they were taking it down.

Is it possible to get the game back online? In any way shape or form.

I was wondering this as since I'm a huge fan, it's the comics, the book, and this that I haven't fully got into. Please give me hope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The game is not available to play anymore.

The game began closed beta-testing in June 2004 which was then opened for people who pre-ordered the game in November 2004. Warner Bros. and Sega officially released MxO on March 22, 2005 in the United States. It was released in Europe on April 15, 2005. The game ran continuously from then until it was **shut down** on July 31, 2009 by Sony Online Entertainment.

Sony Online Entertainment unexpectedly decided to discontinue service to the Matrix Online due to low subscription numbers in June 2009. Sony Online Entertainment shut down the service at 00:00 August 1, 2009. The game had under 500 active players before the shut down.

Comment: Can anyone atest to the amount of craziness I missed out on?

Comment: I personally did not play it but looking at some gameplay videos I would say it  wasn't that good. Also the game had under 500 active players and that says something. If you have not played "The Matrix : Path of Neo" I would recommend it. It has decent metascore of 64 and user score of 8.2. You should check it out

Comment: It had some cool aspects, which is mostly just the super jump.  Nothing special, but the combat sucked (especially after an overhaul to combat).  They were trying to come up with some kind of "Kung Fu Rock-Paper-Scissors" that was not intuitive.  Overall, the other matrix games would be better.

Comment: there might be an open-source / fan-run server out there where you can still play the game. it will likely require some computer skills to repurpose the game code to work with the new server. for example, we play EverQuest 1 Mac on a fan-run server since they sunset the official EQMac server a while back. good luck, neo!

Comment: Yeah I saw one or two fan made servers but I did not know does that counts like promoting piracy so did not want to write anything about it :D

Answer (score 1):

There is now:

[**The Matrix Online Server Emulator** (MxoEmu)](https://mxoemu.info/)

While it does not yet allow you to run your own MxO server, it is at least functional.